# R subsetting data frame by list of characters

Tags: r, character, subset

I have been searching stack overflow for some time about subsetting a data frame, but have not seen a solution that works for me yet.

Here is my data frame:

```
> parsed_nonneg_dm<-as.character(parsed_nonneg_dms$id)
> head(parsed_nonneg_dm)
metagenome    level.1                           level.2
1  4577498.3 METABOLISM Coenzyme transport and metabolism
2  4577500.3 METABOLISM Coenzyme transport and metabolism
3  4577499.3 METABOLISM Coenzyme transport and metabolism
4  4577501.3 METABOLISM Coenzyme transport and metabolism
5  4577497.3 METABOLISM Coenzyme transport and metabolism
6  4577492.3 METABOLISM Coenzyme transport and metabolism
                              function.      id abundance avg.eValue avg..ident
1 Glutamate-1-semialdehyde aminotransferase COG0001        60     -20.62      74.47
2 Glutamate-1-semialdehyde aminotransferase COG0001        61     -19.95      74.15
3 Glutamate-1-semialdehyde aminotransferase COG0001        59     -17.98      74.81
4 Glutamate-1-semialdehyde aminotransferase COG0001       122     -22.24      75.68
5 Glutamate-1-semialdehyde aminotransferase COG0001        86     -20.53      73.33
6 Glutamate-1-semialdehyde aminotransferase COG0001       152     -19.89      73.42
avg.align.len hits file.count   frac.abund max.frac.abund
1         64.12   48      60371 5.117745e-06   0.0002343751
2         62.97   49      58361 6.697885e-06   0.0002343751
3         57.98   50      50630 5.909132e-06   0.0002343751
4         65.76   53      77620 6.325533e-06   0.0002343751
5         64.66   58      72540 7.194086e-06   0.0002343751
6         62.64   84     104735 2.670256e-05   0.0002343751
```

I would like to subset by the ID column and pick out 26 different COG types.I have the COG types I want in a separate data frame:

```
> cogs<-as.data.frame(cogs)
> head(cogs)
    V1
1  COG0110
2  COG0183
3  COG0243
```

I have tried the following code with no success because I can't figure out how to input the data frame "cogs"

```
> call_cogs<-parsed_nonneg_dm[parsed_nonneg_dm$id == cogs[],]
> head(call_cogs)
 [1] metagenome     level.1        level.2        function.      id                      abundance     
 [7] avg.eValue     avg..ident     avg.align.len  hits           file.count     frac.abund    
 [13] max.frac.abund
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I know there is a simple and easy way to call up the second data frame cogs without having to type in the 26 cog IDs I would like to subset. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: `merge(parsed_nonneg_dm, cogs, by.x="id", by.y="V1")`? I can't test this, because you haven't given a reproducible example.

Comment: Don't use equality `==` to test for membership in vector, use `%in%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want '%in%'

```
parsed_nonneg_dm[parsed_nonneg_dm$id %in% cogs$V1,]
```

Reproducible toy example:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(a=LETTERS, b=runif(26))
only_these <- c('N', 'Y', 'C')
df[df$a %in% only_these, ]
```

Gives you:

```
   a         b
3  C 0.4089769
14 N 0.5726334
25 Y 0.6557058
```